# Why simple setState renders once and functional setState renders on each click?

Tags: reactjs

When I use simple setState it renders once and then does not render again.
But when I use functional setState, then it renders with every click. Why?

```
export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  const onClick = () => {
    new Array(3).fill(3).map((a) => setVal(a + 1)); // prints 4 only once
    // new Array(3).fill(3).map((a) => setVal(a=>a + 1)); // prints 4 7 10 on every click
  };

  console.log(val);

  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={onClick}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I understand the difference between **simple setState** and **functional setState**. I just want to know, why simple setState renders component only once here.

For e.g

if I call click with **simple setState** then it renders and shows 4 in console log. If click again it does not render now.

if I click with **functional setState** then it renders and shows 4. If I click again it renders again and prints 7 and so on. It renders on every click.

Why react prevents rendering in **simple setState** more than once ? [Here is the working sample.](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-drake-z7h4g?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: The [documentation for usestate](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) explaines the difference between `setFoo(x)` and `setFoo(x => x + 1)` and why calling them in a loop will produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

*Note, to reduce some noise, I replaced `new Array(3).fill(3)` with `[3, 3, 3]`*

---

In your first example, which reads (equivalently):

```
[3, 3, 3].map(a => setVal(a + 1));
```

`setVal` is called 3 times, with the same value: `3 + 1`. And because react normally [*bails*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) on state updates if the exact same value is used, you'll get one re-render, which in turn logs that constant `4`.

---

In your second example, which reads:

```
[3, 3, 3].map(a => setVal(a => a + 1));
//            ^           ^
//            |           + current state value
//            |
//            + this value is completely ignored, because it's
//              *shadowed* by the latter `a` variable
```

`setVal` is again called 3 times, though this time the return value is dependent on the current state value. Meaning:

```
   + current state (0 initially)
   |   + contant update
   |   |    + next state
   |   |    |  
1) 0 + 1 => 1
            |
   +<<<<<<<<+
   |         
2) 1 + 1 => 2
            |
   +<<<<<<<<+
   |         
3) 2 + 1 => 3
```

And because react [*"may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance"*](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) you also get only one re-render logging `3, 6, 9, ...` respectively.

*Note*: You wrote, the second example logs "4 7 10", though this certainly is not happening with the code you posted. So I'll will assume that's *transfer error*.

Comment: actually it can log "4 7 10" because as you have stated the array filling is totally ignored and the function actually increments the state by 3 each time

Comment: @Martin Ah, that might totally be the case! I just didn't encounter it on my local machine. It's kinda hard to reproduce though.

Comment: Though rereading that, I'm not sure we mean the same thing. Are you referring to the effect that react may or may not batch updates, or something else?

Comment: No I'm not referring to the batched updates. I totally understand the confusion. The question is thoroughly confusing on its own, the `new Array(3).fill(3)` acts totally as a smokescreen together with the wrong usage of `map`. What I mean is that in the first case the state is always updated -and ever will be updated- with the exact same value: 4. But the second case uses `setState(x => x+1)` three times in a row and therefore will with every call of `onClick` actually increment the state by 3. And therefore the log "0, 3, 6, 9..." --AH I GET IT NOW--  "4 7 10" when both lines are commented in

Comment: Doesn't really matter. I think you did a great job with your answer explaining everything.

Comment: Why simple setState is rendering component only once. And functional component is rendering component multiple times ?

Comment: @Piyush See the note under the first code snippet, especially with regards to the link I mentioned.